# How can I do stdin.close() with the new Streams API in Dart?

Tags: io, stream, stdin, dart, dart-io

I ask user for input in my command line (dart:io) app. After I get my answer from the user, I want to unsubscribe from the `Stream`. Then, later, I may want to listen to it again (but with different listener, so `pause()` and `resume()` don't help me).

On startup, I have this:

```
cmdLine = stdin
          .transform(new StringDecoder());
```

Later, when I want to gather input:

```
cmdLineSubscription = cmdLine.listen((String line) {
  try {
    int optionNumber = int.parse(line);
    if (optionNumber >= 1 && optionNumber <= choiceList.length) {
      cmdLineSubscription.cancel();
      completer.complete(choiceList[optionNumber - 1].hash);
    } else {
      throw new FormatException("Number outside the range.");
    }
  } on FormatException catch (e) {
    print("Input a number between 1 and ${choiceList.length}, please.");
  }
});
```

This works as intended, but it leaves `stdin` open at the end of program execution. With the previous API, closing `stdin` was as easy as calling `stdin.close()`. But with the new API, `stdin` is a `Stream`, and those don't have the `close` method.

I think that what I'm doing is closing (read: unsubscribing from) the transformed stream, but leaving the raw (stdin) stream open.

Am I correct? If so, how can I close the underlying `stdin` stream on program exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close `stdin`, you just unsubscribe from it:

```
cmdLineSubscription.cancel();
```

This is the equivalent way of doing it. So your intuition was right. I'm not sure if I understood the question -- was there a problem with this approach?

Comment: Thanks! That line doesn't seem to work for ending stdin, though. After calling `cmdLineSubscription.cancel()`, I can later subscribe again (so, that works), but then on program exit, stdin is still active and waiting for input. I wonder if `cancel()` propagates to Streams that were transformed to the current one (as in stdin -> cmdLine).

Comment: Ok, I just tried to replicate the issue with a clean sheet and couldn't do it, so the problem is somewhere else. `cmdLineSubscription.cancel();` closes `stdin` even if it is transformed, as it should. Thanks for the answer!