# Cancel stdin subscription in combination with LineSplitter

Tags: dart, dart-io

I use `LineSplitter` as a command line interface where every line is a command:

```dart
import "dart:io";
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var sub;

  sub = stdin.transform(UTF8.decoder).transform(new LineSplitter()).listen((l) {
    if (l == "e") {
      sub.cancel();
    }
    print('$l');
  });
}
```

Typing an `e` and a line break should exit the application as the subscribtion is canceled. But this doesn't happen, instead I have to put another line break into stdin. The problem seems to be the `LineSplitter`, maybe it's waiting for the next complete line, is there a way to "undo"/"unchain" the transformer so that the application exits?

Calling `exit` is not an option for me as it exits immediately without correct cleanup.

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186821/how-can-i-do-stdin-close-with-the-new-streams-api-in-dart) question is related, but isn't solved.

Comment: I just tried your code and it works as expected. start the script, type e, enter, app exits. Dart 1.9.0-edge.44564, Debian Linux x64

Comment: Seems to be a problem only on Windows systems, works fine on Linux

Comment: I filled an issue for the Windows problem, but I would still be interested in a workaround: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22940

Comment: Actually the line `sub.cancel()` is called, but the program just does not exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was an issue with the io library in the Dart SDK on Windows and the bug should be fixed now (see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22940)